# pandas average relative elements from multi files

Tags: pandas

I want to average several .csv files which are same dimension, and save as a new file. such as:

```
df_new=avergae(df1,df2,df3.....)
```

Are there any ready function carrying out it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose all your DF columns are numeric and you want to take the mean value across multiple DFs, you can do something like this.

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns, data = np.mean(np.array([df1.values,df2.values,df3.values]),axis=0))
```